# Extract text between two nth occurrences of a character from a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell in Excel with text as follows

```
text1 > text2 > text3 > text4 > text5 > text6
```

I need to find a rule to extract the some of the text and put it in another cell for example like this (the order may vary):

```
text6 text3 text5
```

I tried different solutions but they don't really work as expected:

```
=TRIM(MID(D6,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(D6,">","#",2))+1,255))

=REPLACE(D7,1,FIND("^^",SUBSTITUTE(D7,">","^^",8))+1,"")

=RIGHT(D4,LEN(D4)-SEARCH("#",SUBSTITUTE(D4,">","#",LEN(D4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D4,">","")))))&" "&MID(D4, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(D4,">",CHAR(1),3))+2, FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(D4,">",CHAR(1),3)) - FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(D4,">",CHAR(1),2))-11)
```

Can you help me with that? Thanks

EDIT: Found the solution! This rule is working fine for me. If you change the value of X you change the number of the occurrencies:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(">" & D5&REPT(" ",6),">",REPT(",",255)),X*255,255),",","")
```

Comment: Use [FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml)

Comment: *I need to find a rule to extract the some of the text* No, you need to develop a rule, and then code it.  Without knowing the rule or rules you want to use, one would need to be a good guesser to figure what rules might be appropriate.  I don't really see how you expect to obtain the results you show from your data input.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Do you have any recommendations for where to start? What functions are most appropriate to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Found the solution, thanks for the help.